# use a function to display a grade for each test score the user inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I want to send 5 test scores through one function in Python and have that function display a letter grade for each one. I am also getting the average of these scores. here is what I have so far:

```
testscore1 = float(input('Enter first test score: '))

testscore2 = float(input('Enter second test score: '))

testscore3 = float(input('Enter third test score: '))

testscore4 = float(input('Enter fourth test score: '))

testscore5 = float(input('Enter fifth test score: '))

listofscores = (testscore1,testscore2,testscore3,testscore4,testscore5)

def calcAverage():
  average = (testscore1+testscore2+testscore3+testscore4+testscore5)/5
  return average

def determineGrade(listofscores):
  for i in listofscores
  testscore1 = round(testscore1)
  if listofscores > 100:
      return "please enter a real score"
  elif listofscores <= 100 and listofscores >=90:
      return "your grade is an A"
  elif listofscores >= 80 and listofscores <= 89:
      return "your grade is a B"
  elif listofscores >= 70 and listofscores <= 79:
      return "your grade is a C"
  elif listofscores >= 60 and listofscores <= 69:
      return "your grade is a D"
  elif listofscores < 60: 
      return "your grade is an F"


print(determineGrade(),calcAverage())
```

how do I pass all scores into the grade function and display each grade for each score?

Answer (score 0):

here

```
     determineGrade(testscore1)
Should be:
     determineGrade(listofscores)
```